# How to passthrough request cancellation through api gateway

Tags: node.js, angular, aws-api-gateway

We have next schema:
Angular app -> AWS API Gateway -> Micro service(node.js)

User clicks on cancel button for some slow processing. Frontend angular app cancels http request. But node.js app doesn't see that request is closed

```
req.on('close', err => { // we also checked with 'aborted' event
  if (!err) {
    console.log('request was closed')  // <-- doesn't get called
  }
})
```

I assume it's because we use api gateway. But how to teach it to forward request cancelation to node.js?

API gateway [error handling doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/handling-errors/) wasn't very helpful.